# Get a rows of number inside a textbox inside a table and compute its total

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table and in the last column, there is rows of number inside a textbox. I'm trying to loop through those rows and get each number inside the text box. Once all the numbers are gathered, all of it will be added. I'm looking to for it to be added once I click the "calculate" button.

I tried taking the content of the cell vie tableName.rows[n].cells[n].innerHTML but that does not work coz the text it still inside the text box. I'm not even sure if that's how you get a text inside table cells/

```js
let mealObj = {
  menu1: {
    menuName: "Steak",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Butter",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "2",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "10",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Parsley",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "1",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Garlic",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Soy Sauce",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Beef",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "3/4",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "200",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Salt",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "0",
    },
    ingr7: {
      name: "Pepper",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
  },
}

let ingrTable = document.getElementById("ingr-table");
objToTable(mealObj);

function objToTable(ingrList) {
let totalRowLength = ingrTable.rows.length;
  for (let i in ingrList) {
    for (let k in ingrList[i]) {
      if (ingrList[i][k].name !== undefined) {
          let tableAmount = document.createElement("INPUT");
          tableAmount.setAttribute("type", "number");
          tableAmount.id = "table-amount";
          let tableCalNum = document.createElement("INPUT");
          tableCalNum.setAttribute("type", "number");
          tableCalNum.id = "table-cal";

          let row = ingrTable.insertRow(totalRowLength);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          cell1.innerHTML = ingrList[i][k].name;
          cell2.appendChild(tableAmount);
          tableAmount.value = eval(ingrList[i][k].amount);
          cell3.innerHTML = ingrList[i][k].amountType;
          cell4.appendChild(tableCalNum);
          tableCalNum.value = ingrList[i][k].cal;
      }
    }
  }
}

let button = document.getElementById("button");
let calculateBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
calculateBtn.innerHTML = "Calculate";
button.appendChild(calculateBtn);

calculateBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < ingrTable.rows.length; i++) {
    calNum = document.getElementById("table-cal");
    console.log(calNum.value);
    //console.log(ingrTable.rows[i].cells[3]);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
<table id="ingr-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Ingredient</th>
            <th colspan="2">Amount</th>
            <th>Calorie</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
let mealObj = {
  menu1: {
    menuName: "Steak",
    ingr1: {name:"Butter",  ingrType: "other",  amount: "2",  amountType: "tbsp",  cal: "10",},
    ingr2: {name:"Parsley",  ingrType: "vegetable",  amount: "1",  amountType: "tsp",  cal: "1",},
    ingr3: {name:"Garlic",  ingrType: "vegetable",  amount: "1/2",  amountType: "tsp",  cal: "20",},
    ingr4: {name:"Soy Sauce",  ingrType: "other",  amount: "1/4",  amountType: "tsp",  cal: "20",},
    ingr5: {name:"Beef",  ingrType: "meat",  amount: "3/4",  amountType: "lbs",  cal: "200",},
    ingr6: {name:"Salt",  ingrType: "other",  amount: "1/8",  amountType: "tsp",  cal: "0",},
    ingr7: {name:"Pepper",  ingrType: "other",  amount: "1/8",  amountType: "tsp",  cal: "2",},
  },
};
const mknum = (str) =>  Function('"use strict";return (' + str.trim().replace(/ +/,"+") + ")")();
const tbl=document.querySelector("#ingr-table tbody");

tbl.innerHTML=Object.values(mealObj.menu1).slice(1).map(r=>
 `<tr><td>${r.name}</td><td><input type="text" value="${r.amount}"></td>
    <td>${r.amountType}</td><td><input type="text" value="${r.cal}"></td></tr>` ).join("\n")
 +'<tr><td>Sum</td><td id="asum"></td><td></td><td id="csum"></td></tr>';  
const amnts=[...tbl.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(2) input")], asum=document.getElementById("asum"),
      cals=[...tbl.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(4) input")],  csum=document.getElementById("csum"),
      summation=()=>{ asum.textContent=amnts.reduce((a,c)=>{try{return a+=mknum(c.value)}catch{return a}},0);
                      csum.textContent=cals.reduce((a,c)=>a+=+c.value,0);};
                      
tbl.addEventListener("input", ev=>ev.target.tagName==="INPUT" && summation() )
summation();
```

```html
<table id="ingr-table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Ingredient</th>
       <th colspan="2">Amount</th>
       <th>Calorie</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>              
</table>
```

I tried to make the summation of the `amounts` column behave as stable as possible, but clearly, it does not make sense at all to add numbers with different units! So, this can only be seen as a "playful exercise" without any real purpose.

The function `mknum()` will try to convert a fraction given in the form of an integer + `blank` + fractional part into a numeric value. It will fail, if the string begins or ends with a `/`. For these cases I built in the `try{..} catch{..}` construct.